# Delphi-7: Convert yyyymmdd formatted string(format without a separator) to DateTime object

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I'm using **Delphi7**.

I have date format set to **yyyymmdd** (can take any date format without separator). When I'm trying `StrToDate('20170901')` it is throwing error.

I want to support all the valid date formats (can be used by different clients in different zones.)

I have tried with `VarToDateTime` but it is also not working.

If same issue will be there for DateToStr() also, please guide me through that too.

Comment: @LURD: My mistake, I have updated the details. If possible please remove negative marking so at least I can get my solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is quite trivial to pick out the components of such a string using, for instance Copy. They can then be passed to StrToInt and then to EncodeDate.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: but what if regional setting of the system has been changed to '1-Sept-2017'. I need to take care of all possible formats.

Comment: You are very confused. You asked about one specific format. No mention of region settings. You need to decide exactly what you are trying to do, where the data is coming from etc.

Comment: For any date format which is having a date separator, it is working fine. Ex.dd-mm-yyyy, dd-mm-yy, mm/dd/yy.

But when client changes server's date format which is not having any separator it is not working with StrToDate().
Ex. yyyyMMdd, ddMMyyyy.

Comment: Do you expect magic? Just write you own routine based on "server's date format" string. Simple approach - insert separators between groups.

Comment: @user3085495  So what is `02/04/2017`?  Feb 4th or Apr 2nd?  Or what about `20112004`? Apr 20, 2011?  Nov 20, 2004?    You cannot possibly handle all date formats.  You can handle known formats and you can handle formats based on the user's environment and localization but it is impossible to handle **all** possible formats - there will always be multiple available interpretations.

Comment: The first step is to try to understand where the input data comes from. Before we can even answer the question you need to work out what the question is. It's a common beginner mistake. Coding before understanding the problem. You have to step make and gain a true understanding of the problem.

Comment: It is best to use a standardized date format that is not subject to any specific regional format, like [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601).

Answer (score 8):

You are getting an error because your input string does not match your machine's regional settings for date/time strings.

Normally, I would suggest using the `StrToDate()` function in the `SysUtils` unit, setting its global `ShortDateFormat` and `DateSeparator` variables beforehand, and then restore them afterwards (Delphi 7 predates the introduction of the `TFormatSettings` record), eg:

```
uses
  ..., SysUtils;

var
  OldShortDateFormat: string;
  OldDateSeparator: Char;
  input: string;
  dt: TDateTime;
begin
  input := ...;

  OldShortDateFormat := ShortDateFormat;
  OldDateSeparator := DateSeparator;
  ShortDateFormat := 'yyyymmdd'; // or whatever format you need...
  DateSeparator := '/'; // or whatever you need
  try
    dt := StrToDate(input);
  finally
    ShortDateFormat := OldShortDateFormat;
    DateSeparator := OldDateSeparator;
  end;

  // use dt as needed...
end;
```

Unfortunately, `StrToDate()` *requires* the input string to have a separator between the date components (ie `2017/09/01`), but your input string does not (`20170901`).  `StrToDate()` does not allow `DateSeparator` to be set to `#0` when parsing a string, even if the `ShortDateFormat` does not specify any separators are in the format.

So that leaves only one option - parse the string manually to extract the individual components, and then use the `EncodeDate()` function in the `SysUtils` unit, eg:

```
uses
  ..., SysUtils;

var
  wYear, wMonth, wDay: Word;
  input: string;
  dt: TDateTime;
begin
  input := ...;

  wYear := StrToInt(Copy(input, 1, 4));
  wMonth := StrToInt(Copy(input, 5, 2));
  wDay := StrToInt(Copy(input, 7, 2));
  // or in whatever order you need...

  dt := EncodeDate(wYear, wMonth, wDay);

  // use dt as needed...
end;
```

The `DateToStr()` function is also subject to regional settings.  However, it does allow the `DateSeparator` to be omitted in the output.  So, you can either:

1. use `DateToStr()`, setting the global `ShortDateFormat` variable to the desired format:

   ```
   uses
     ..., SysUtils;

   var
     OldShortDateFormat: string;
     dt: TDateTime;
     output: string;
   begin
     dt := ...;

     OldShortDateFormat := ShortDateFormat;
     ShortDateFormat := 'yyyymmdd'; // or whatever format you need...
     try
       output := DateToStr(dt);
     finally
       ShortDateFormat := OldShortDateFormat;
     end;

     // use output as needed...
   end;
   ```
2. extract the individual date components from the `TDateTime` using the `DecodeDate()` function in the `SysUtils` unit, and then format your own string with the year/month/day values however you want:

   ```
   uses
     ..., SysUtils;

   var
     wYear, wMonth, wDay: Word;
     dt: TDateTime;
     output: string;
   begin
     dt := ...;

     DecodeDate(dt, wYear, wMonth, wDay);
     output := Format('%.4d%.2d%.2d', [wYear, wMonth, wDay]);

     // use output as needed...
   end;
   ```

Comment: Very nice approach the second one

Answer (score 5):

To convert that string into a `TDateTime`, split the string into its year, month and day components and pass them to the `EncodeDate()` function.

```
var
  myStr: string;
  myDate: TDate;
begin
  myStr := '20170901';
  myDate := EncodeDate(
    StrToInt(Copy(MyStr, 1, 4)),
    StrToInt(Copy(MyStr, 5, 2)),
    StrToInt(Copy(MyStr, 7, 2))
  );
  ...
end;
```

Comment: Unfortunately you neglected to account for 1 based indexing of strings. And not using a variable for the string is weak. Finally, the asker wants to do way more than this, but the question is unclear.

Comment: It was a suggestion of a way to solve his problem, of course he can apply the best practices. I'm being pratical.

Comment: You ignored the detail in my comment